# No sound in Youtube since falshplugin-installer updated 14/09/15

Tags: 14.04, updates, firefox, flash

So title says it really, updated and then no sound ONLY for YouTube, all other flash seems fine.

The update downloaded and installed fine.

I tried reinstalling the plug in as well as the restricted extras, reinstalled Firefox too, also Google results were all dated and not relevant.

Am I the only one getting this ?

Anyone know a fix ?

Ubuntu 14.04
Nvidia gtx 650

Shockwave Flash

```
File: libflashplayer.so
Path: /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
Version: 11.2.202.508
State: Enabled
Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202
```

Comment: Maybe you clicked mute in the player. And you can watch Youtube without flash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 version of Youtube instead of the flash version - to enable it go to https://www.youtube.com/html5 and enable it:

[image: It should say 'The HTML5 player is currently used when possible']

You need the appropriate video codecs to do this, you should have them if `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package is installed (see [RestrictedFormats](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats) - these codecs may also be installed with Totem, VLC or other video players.

If the issue is with the HTML5 player, you can switch back to the flash player using the [youtube.com/html5](https://www.youtube.com/html5) page again

If you have issues with high-quality playback etc, try my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/662184/178596).

---

Another possible issue is that its volume has been muted - make sure it isn't like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it seems I already had it checked and also has no sound, I guess this must be a youtube issue then ? Will probably be off topic now

Comment: Could be... - does Firefox/Youtube/whatever show in 'Applications under Sound Settings?

Comment: Yes it did, it was muted, don't know why, all other sounds in Firefox were working, just not youtube, please edit the answer to reflect this and I will gladly accept for your help