# In youtube, There are just 360p and 720p options .(no 240p,480p and 1080p)

Tags: firefox, video, youtube, display-resolution

A couple of days before, everything is working perfectly good. But After last Ubuntu update -also flash player has updated- (I just think that was occurred after update but maybe not) I can not watch 1080p, 480p and 240 videos in youtube. Actually there is no option just 360p and 720p. I tried to reinstall both Firefox and flash player but nothing change. I thing this problem just related with youtube. Because I can watch 1080p videos from vimeo.com and other websites. Please help me.

A picture from https://www.youtube.com/html5

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTML5 is usually better than Flash ([particularly security wise](http://uk.businessinsider.com/adobe-flash-security-flaws-prove-we-need-to-move-to-html5-2015-7)), just Youtube's implementation uses Media Source Extensions, which is available in Firefox but disabled by default currently *(**EDIT:** in recent Firefox this should no longer be a issue (since version 44) - IF you have the appropiate codecs installed on your system):*

- [Why you can’t play 1080p or 480p YouTube HTML5 videos in Firefox anymore](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/10/27/youtube-videos-firefox-1080p/) - Nov 5 2013
- [no option for 1080p youtube](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1043379#answer-682328) - Jan 25 2015
- [How to get 1080p in Youtube’s HTML5 player in Firefox (on Linux)](http://www.linuxveda.com/2015/06/29/get-1080p-youtubes-html5-player-firefox-linux/) - Jun 29 2015

To fix it, basically go to `about:config` and:

- ignore the warranty dragons
- set the `media.mediasource.enabled` & `media.mediasource.webm.enabled` entries to `true`
  [image]

The [YouTube HTML5 player enabling page](https://www.youtube.com/html5) should look at minimum like this:

[image: working html5 player enabled screenshots]

<sup>The more blue things the merrier</sup>

Then sit back and enjoy 1080p playback (if it doesn't need to buffer for half a hour due to broadband bandwidth like mine does :)

---

If you need to enable MSE & H264, you should be able to do so using the method suggested [here](http://www.ghacks.net/2014/07/25/enable-mse-h2-64-support-youtube-firefox-right-now/) in `about:config`:

- Create a new boolean key called `media.mediasource.ignore_codecs` and set it to 'True' - it may now work so check https://www.youtube.com/html5
- If it does not work yet, do the following:

  - Set `media.mediasource.mp4.enabled` to 'True'
  - Set to 'True' all the things begining with `media.fragmented-mp4` - except for `media.fragmented-mp4.use-blank-decoder` which needs to be set to 'False':
    [image]

All should then work (does for me with Firefox Beta AND ffmpeg available... for ffmpeg on 14.* releases try [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04)):
[image]

---

**EDIT:** In Firefox 43 at least, doing the above may break the HTML5 player. There seems to be other issues ([atleast with Firefox's useragent](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=206285#p1586831)), but anyway if it breaks try setting `media.fragmented-mp4.gmp.enabled` to `false` ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/3x2eg1/firefox_43_crashes_on_all_videos_fi_youtube_vids/))

**EDIT:** again in Firefox 44 (with the default FF useragent) some issues may occur, though for me it shows a error about HTML5 videos when actually becuase videos have been blocked for other reasons (e.g. copyright). <del>I am now forcing HTML5 with [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-all-html5)</del>
**Another edit:** now doesn't seem necessary on fresh profiles, possibly due to https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/44.0/releasenotes/#new

Answer (score 2):

the problem is with the YouTube HTML5 player, I had the same problem and fixed at by installing flash plug-in. then go to [this link](https://www.youtube.com/html5) and choose to disable the `html5` player if it's still the default.

Afterwards, it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: HTML5 is usually better, just youtube's implementation ([using Media Source Extensions, currently unsupported in FF](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/10/27/youtube-videos-firefox-1080p/))... :/ Anyway there is a fix suggested [here](http://www.linuxveda.com/2015/06/29/get-1080p-youtubes-html5-player-firefox-linux/) and another [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1043379#answer-682328).

Comment: yourube html5 player still has some problems @wilf

Comment: @Wilf For me, I get this problem only on Ubuntu 14.04 and FF40, but Windows 7 with FF40 is fine, and Media Source Extensions are active.

Comment: MSE works on my Fedora testing build of Firefox 40 (my current ubuntu machines are mainly servers, can't test :), it will show as enabled (bottom left) box [here](https://www.youtube.com/html5) if it is. Enabling `media.mediasource.enabled` and `media.mediasource.webm.enabled` seem enough.

Comment: @RonnieDroid thank you for your reply. But I can't find a option to disable html5 player.

Comment: It will be use the default player, not disable HTML5 player. @al0s

Comment: Did you try to clean firefox cach?  for me it worked just as i installed flahsplayer-plugin.

Comment: @al0s you marked my answer as the right answer, did it work for you? if it didn't you don't have to do that

Comment: I actually use @Wilf' s solution. Flashplayer-plugin has been installed for long time ago in my system.

Comment: @al0s up-vote his answers, and don't mark my answer as the correct one, because it didn't help you. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be caused by the lack of H.264 codec support on Firefox.

Installing the FFmpeg plugin for GStreamer solved this problem for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```