# Youtube videos of all the format doesnot play in Ubuntu 14.04 Firefox 40

Tags: 14.04, firefox, flash, youtube

Youtube videos of all the format doesn't play in Ubuntu 14.04 Firefox 40.

Only 360p is playing. But all resolutions works fine in Chromium. But I want to use Firefox as default.

Is it flash player related issue ?
After little bit Google I have installed `freshplayerplugin`
but still same problem. Is there any way to solve this ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [**In youtube, There are just 360p and 720p options .(no 240p,480p and 1080p)**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/661558/in-youtube-there-are-just-360p-and-720p-options-no-240p-480p-and-1080p).

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the lack of H.264 codec support on Firefox.

Try to install the FFmpeg plugin for GStreamer :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

Comment: Can you provide some support to your answer?