# YouTube doesn't change video quality

Tags: 14.04

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Mozilla Firefox browser.

When I go to YouTube its default is 720p (HD) but when I try to change it the check mark goes to the quality I pick but it doesn't change. It is still on 720p:

[image]

How can I select a lower quality?

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/40j64Xm.png

Comment: I could switch to 1080HD on the same clip. So it is something with your Firefox or internet speed. I think if the connection is too slow, it is hard to switch to higher resolution. Try lower resolution and see if it switches. And try another browser, Chrome for example.

Comment: try [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-high-definition/?src=userprofile) addon.

Comment: biocyberman, my problem is i can only switch in HD. What I want is to switch to a lower quality.

Comment: Also duplicated with "http://askubuntu.com/questions/661558/in-youtube-there-are-just-360p-and-720p-options-no-240p-480p-and-1080p"

Comment: Flash or HTML5? And how do you know that it doesn't actually change? The transition between different streams of the same video are quite smooth on Youtube, often you can't actually see them.

Comment: @mastov I'm fairly confident you would notice the 720 / 480 change.

Comment: Mastov, I know it doesn't change because it still is in HD. I tried it in 144p and it's still is

Comment: @al0s Definetlally not a dupe - he has all the options - see the image he posted.

Comment: I tried every option

Comment: @Tim, I see you are right it is not dupe.  Is there any possibility to fix the problem by purging and reinstalling firefox?

Comment: Nothing is bad with giving  a change to reinstall if you have not limited Internet connection.  1. "sudo apt-get purge firefox" 2. "sudo apt-get update" 3."sudo apt-get install firefox" CAUTION: Maybe your bookmarks will be deleted. I have no idea with it. My suggestion restore it before giving first command.

Comment: But my bookmarks will be gone. :(

Comment: Tried it guys. Purging firefox, still no luck.

Comment: Yeeeeeeeelpppppp

Answer (score 0):

Check these two threads. I quoted the relevant sections for your convenience:

https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/509254-Can-t-change-YouTube-video-resolution-in-Firefox

Hello,

> Either set `media.mediasource.enabled` and
>   `media.mediasource.webm.enabled` to true in Firefox's about:config or
>   install flash-player.
>
> Regards,
>
> Antoine

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/974108

> Clear the cache and cookies only from websites that cause problems.
>
> "Clear the Cache":
>
> Firefox/Tools > Options > Advanced > Network > Cached Web Content:
>   "Clear Now" "Remove Cookies" from sites causing problems:
>
> Firefox/Tools > Options > Privacy > Cookies: "Show Cookies"

Another method from the same thread

> Dear, Everyone who cares. I've had the same solution on and off for
>   weeks, and I have just now found my solution. Try LOGGING OFF.
>   Something in the account settings was doing it for me, but Logging off
>   of my youtube / gmail account fixed this problem.
>
> Spread the word.

Comment: First option, both are already set to true, tried the others and still not working.