# I cannot play audio in Firefox, KODI and other video streams, video is fine, just no audio

Tags: sound, vlc

After an update yesterday to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS,  I no longer have audio when I play a video from Youtube, KODI, or other video streams.

I can play audio using Jack/Alsa using the VLC player, so it is not my hardware.  Something must have been changed during the update yesterday.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: This might be what happed to me, this might help http://askubuntu.com/questions/661483/no-sound-in-youtube-since-falshplugin-installer-updated-14-09-15 See the second part of the answer

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Mark.  My problem is that all sites do not play sound.  So even it the HTML5 fix works for Youtube specifically, it will not likely fix KODI and other streaming video sites as well as Virtual Box running Win7 that are all missing sound now after the update.

Comment: See the bottom of that answer about checking to see if it is muted, open firefox, then go to sound settings and under applications see if it is muted, happed to me after an update the other day, html5 was not the fix if you read the comments

Comment: Understood Mark.  Alsamixer is not muted or I could not play MP3's using VLC.   By the way, I use a variant called KXStudio which is based upon Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get audio back by starting a program called Cadence and then within Cadence starting JACK and then starting the ALSA->Loop->Jack bridge.

I have no idea why this is now needed, but then I have no idea what very recent update disabled audio from automatically playing. With JACK and the ALSA to JACK brige running, I now have audio again from KODI,  Youtube in Firefox and Win7 in VirtualBox. I guess I will never know what happened, but at least I have this work around.